# Spring MongoDB Criteria: How to check that the List exists and contains object with specific value?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How to check that the `List<Object>` exists and contains an object of class whose `partnerRole` field value is equal to `"CREATOR"` and `companyId` field value is equals to `"123"`?

Document class:

```
@Document
public class ApplicationDocument {
    List<PartnerDocument> partners = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Document
public class PartnerDocument {

  private PartnerRole partnerRole;
  private String companyId;
  ...

  public enum PartnerRole {
    UNKNOWN_ROLE,
    CREATOR,
    PARTICIPANT
  }
}
```

My method for generating a `List` of `Criteria`. But that won't work because I'm referring to `partners` as if it were a `PartnerDocument` object, but `partners` is actually a `List<PartnerDocument>`.

```java
  public  List<Criteria> getCriteria(Partner.PartnerRole role, String companyId) {
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("partners").exists(true));
    criteriaList.add(
        Criteria.where("partners.partnerRole").in(role)
    );
    criteriaList.add(
        Criteria.where("partners.partnerRole").in(companyId)
    );
    return criteriaList;
  }
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your second criteria. `Criteria.where("partners.partnerRole").in(companyId)` You are checking companyId against partnerRole

Comment: Of course, add. I thought my problem was due to the use of a list in a field. But everything turned out to be easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your second criteria.

```
Criteria.where("partners.partnerRole").in(companyId)
```

You are checking companyId against partnerRole.

It should be

```
Criteria.where("partners.companyId").in(companyId)
```